How to get numeric code from Name and Date?
i want to generate a numeric code from a data consist of name date and a number
A4 has Name = Joel Bansode > this can have multiple combination see the link
B4 has a valid Date
C4 has a numeric value
the result from this data should have this no. >> 0010503241002
p.s. 001 came from C4, 050324 from may 03 2024 B4, 10 from J in Joel 02 from B in last name Bansode - final 0010503241002
i am using the formula here =TEXT(C4, "000") & TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(B4)), "00") & TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(B4)), "00") & RIGHT(YEAR(DATEVALUE(B4)), 2) & TEXT(CODE(UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A4, FIND(" ", A4)-1), " ", ""))) - 64, "00") & TEXT(CODE(UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A4, FIND(" ", A4)+1, LEN(A4)), " ", ""))) - 64, "00")
but when i change A4 name like add spaces multiple times or add a middle name i dont get proper results see A5 and A6
google sheet link here


You may try:
=text(C4,"000")&text(B4,"mmddyy")&
 join(,index(text(code(regexextract(A4,"^([A-Z]).*([A-Z])[^ ]*$"))-64,"00")))



gives error if not proper case

try with proper() as such: regexextract(proper(A4)

but this gives error
Code below worked fine in all scenarios just that its not taking the last word from cell A, always going for the second one
=TEXT(C8, "000") & TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(B8)), "00") & TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(B8)), "00") & RIGHT(YEAR(DATEVALUE(B8)), 2) & TEXT(CODE(UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A8, FIND(" ", A8)-1), " ", ""))) - 64, "00") & TEXT(CODE(UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A8, FIND(" ", A8)+1, LEN(A8)), " ", ""))) - 64, "00")
